# Update application state after maxAttempts using spring-cloud-stream with rabbitmq

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'm using spring-cloud-stream to communicate between services. I've configured the RepublishMessageRecoverer with 3 maxAttempts and also configured the consumer input binding with autoBindDlq and republishToDlq.

The republish is working fine. I just would like to to detect that all attempts have been tried and update the application state so it reflects a error state. If I could get the counter also would solve my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: post your code and configurations for better chances of getting help

Answer (score 0):

The internal retry context (containing the delivery count) is not exposed to the application.

We are working on a new error handling strategy that will allow you to subscribe to an error channel along with the republishing recoverer so you will be able to get a notification that way.

I don't have a good solution for you with the current binder.

I suppose you could do something with a 2-stage DLQ.

Add a second `StreamListener`, consuming from the main listener's DLQ and have it send inbound messages to the final DLQ.

If a message flows through the second listener, it means there was a failure in the main listener.

It's a bit convoluted, though.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that. It does seem a little to much of overhead for a workaround. Any estimate on when this new error handling strategy might be out?

Comment: It should be on master in a week or so; I think the first milestone for 1.3 will be out early July.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into what I can do with the timing.